# monotone convergence theorem and calculaton of Hausdorff dimension

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification, examples-counterexamples, fractals, hausdorff-measure

I'm reading [these notes](https://sites.math.washington.edu/%7Efarbod/teaching/cornell/math6210pdf/math6210Hausdorff.pdf), and I'm stuck on an application of the monotone convergence theorem. In computing the Hausdorff dimension of the Koch curve (page 13), the authors show that

1. $H^p(S^{i+1}(A)) > H^p(S^i(A))$ for all $i$
2. $H^p(K)$ is a finite limit of the sequence $H^p(S^{i}(A))$

where the $S^i(A)$ are the $i^{th}$ iteration of the recursive construction of the Koch curve, $K = \lim_{i \to \infty} S^i(A)$ is the Koch curve, and $p$ is the Hausdorff dimension of $K$. $H^p(X)$ is the Hausdorff measure of a set $X$.

The authors then use the monotone convergence theorem to conclude
$$H^p(\lim_{i \to \infty} S^i(A)) = \lim_{i \to \infty} H^p(S^i(A)).$$
I'm not much of an analyst and really struggling to see how this is an application of the monotone convergence theorem. I'm used to this theorem being the statement that limits commute with integrals in the case of positive integrable functions in an increasing sequence. **I don't see where the functions, or the integrals are in the above statement - could someone explain what the relevant measures, integrals, and functions are?**

*Edit*: I've added a bounty because I still haven't gotten a satisfying answer here or found one any other way. I'm aware that the argument presented in the linked text might be incorrect/insufficiently rigorous, so I would also accept a rigorous computation using other methods, as long as they remain "at the level" of the paper (i.e. I've seen some methods that rely on Radon measures and some other measure theory background I'm not familiar with. I would accept an answer that is rigorous but doesn't use these methods).

Comment: That article does not, in fact, define what is "$\lim_{i \to \infty} S^i(A)$". The correct definition may not be as straightforward as the visual image might make you believe.

Comment: I have no clue of that "monotone convergence theorem", although I have seen lots of similar ones.

Comment: Since they are referencing Folland's analysis, I assume that the limit of sets they are thinking of is the one defined there. In that case, the limit works out to the set of all points that are in all but finitely many of the $S^i(A)$, I believe

Comment: Your statement, "the limit works out to the set of all points that are in all but finitely many of the $S^i(A)$" demonstrates that "the correct definition may not be as straightforward as" many would think.  In fact, most of points in $K$ are not in any of $S^i(A)$!

Comment: I see - that definition of limit of sets won't include limit points. So what is a better definition for $K$, or for limit of a sequence of sets in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no wonder you are suspicious of that article.

##### It is wrong that "$H^p(S^{i+1}(A)) > H^p(S^i(A))$ for all $i$"

In fact, $H^p(S^{i+1}(A))=H^p(S^{i}(A))=0$ for all $i$.

Here is why. Since $S^i(A)$ is a union of finitely many (straight) line segments, $H^1(S^{i}(A))$ is finite. By the theorem in section $3.1$ of that article, $H^p(S^i(A))=0$ since, as we know from elsewhere, $p=\frac{\log 4}{\log3}>1$.

By the way, that article reads "$p=\frac{\log 4}{\log(1/3)}\approx1.26$" on page $14$. That is an obvious typo, since $\log(1/3)<0$.

##### It is wrong that "$H^p(K)$ is a finite limit of the sequence $H^p(S^{i}(A))$"

As said above, $H^p(S^{i}(A))=0$ for all $i$. Their limit is $0$ while $H^p(K)$ is, as we know from elsewhere, nonzero.

##### A note on the definition of Hausdorff dimension

That article, *Hausdorff Measure* by Jimmy Briggs and Tim Tyree only defines Hausdorff dimension when the Haudorff measure is a finite, nonzero number.

> Definition. We then see that if $H^p(A)$ is a finite nonzero value, then for all $k \in [0, +\infty)$ such that $k\not=p$, $H^k(A)$ is either infinite or zero. Then, we define the Hausdorff Dimension of set $A$, $\dim H(A) = p$ if and only if $H^p(A)$ is a finite, nonzero number.

However, such $p$ may not exist for some metric spaces, even if they are closed subsets of a finite-dimensional Euclidean space.

- There is a closed subset $M_{\frac12}$ of $\Bbb R$ such that

  - $H^p(M_\frac12)=\infty$ if $p<\frac12$ and
  - $H^p(M_\frac12)=0$ if $p\ge\frac12$.
- There is a closed subset $N_{\frac12}$ of $\Bbb R$ such that

  - $H^p(N_\frac12)=\infty$ if $p\le\frac12$ and
  - $H^p(N_\frac12)=0$ if $p>\frac12$.

The number $\frac12$ above could be replaced any number in $(0,1)$.

It turns out that article does not even prove the Koch curve does have a Hausdorff dimension according to its own definition!

Please check other definitions of Hausdorff dimension such as [the one on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_dimension#Hausdorff_dimension).

Comment: In fact, the definition in the article is not even applicable to $\Bbb R^n$, the standard $n$-dimensional space.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to that Wikipedia article, that's a very useful point! Do you know a method to compute what we "know from elsewhere", i.e. that $p = \frac{\log 4}{\log 3}$? Or have a good reference for these computations that is more approachable than the last chapter of Folland? If so that would be fantastic! If no one is able to provide one in the next couple of days though, I'll accept and give you the bounty before it expires, because this is a very helpful response!

Comment: What is defined in that article is called "strict Hausdorff dimension" in paper [*Hausdorff dimension and its applications*](https://math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2009/REUPapers/Shah.pdf) by JAY SHAH.

Comment: Theorem 3.9 in that paper by Jay Shah proves that the Hausdorff dimension of some self-similar set is given by $\frac{\log n}{\log\frac1r}$, where $n$ is the number of copies of  similarity ratio $r$.  Applying to Koch curve, we got $\frac{\log4}{\log3}$.

Comment: Ok, looking through that paper gives most of what I needed: a proof that the Hausdorff dimension is $\frac{\log n}{\log 1/r}$ that is fairly accessible without a lot of measure theory background, so I've accepted the answer. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome!